# Is my proof of 'inscribed angle theorem' different from the usual one?

Tags: geometry, proof-verification, euclidean-geometry, triangles, alternative-proof

The [usual proof of inscribed circle theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle) uses the fact that the sum of interior angles is equal to exterior angle. I've formulated a little different approach, although the underlying concept is still to use isosceles triangle properties. I want to know whether my proof has anything original or not. The proof is,

[image]

A,B and C are thrre vertices of the triagnle and O is the circumcenter. By the property of isosceles triangle we have $\delta = \delta _1, \alpha = \alpha _1$ and $\beta = \beta _2$

Now, $$(\angle A - \alpha)+(\angle C - \beta) = 180 - \angle AOC$$
$$\implies \angle AOC = \left( 180-(\angle A + \angle C) \right) + (\beta + \alpha)$$
$$\implies  \angle AOC = \angle B + \angle B = 2 \angle B$$

> - So the question is, have I done something original?

Comment: There are more than one way to prove the validity of the said theorem and some are more simpler.

Comment: @Mick Could you give a link to those proofs?

Comment: Search for "angle at center is twice the angle at circumference".